# Converting a push on/push off SPDT switch into a toggle

Tags: switches, teensy, spdt

I'm working on a small electronics project: trying to convert a guitar footswitch into a push-to-talk foot pedal.

At my disposal, I've got a Teensy acting as the actual HID device (to be connected to a computer via USB), a single-pole double-throw footswitch button [identical to this one](https://vetco.net/products/spdt-push-button-switch-on-on-15a), and the footswitch case itself.

My issue is that I'd like this footswitch to be a toggle: at a high level, putting your foot down should enable speech capture, while releasing it mutes a connected microphone.

Is it possible to reliably implement this kind of logic in the Teensy given that the switch I've got on hand is a push on/push off?

Comment: actually it's push on push on, not on off.

Comment: It sounds like the largest problem you may have is of disabling the *mechanical* push-on/push-off latching mechanism, unless that isn't part of the change you need.  It's possible you might be able to insert some sort of block which would prevent it from depressing far enough to actuate that.  You could always find a simple momentary switch like a cheap keyboard's sustain pedal.

Comment: You're conflating two concepts: SPDT describes the arrangement of the contacts, while push on/push off vs. momentary describes the mechanical arrangement of the actuator. Two entirely different things.

Comment: @DaveTweed yup, you're right! Updated the title to reflect that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm looking at workarounds at the software level before disassembling the switch to alter it mechanically, but any suggestions along either avenue are welcome.

Comment: Think about how this usually works: you push the space bar, the movie pauses, you push it again it resumes.  So typically you'd have your HID device just send press/release events, and the application software do the toggling.  But if you want to put the toggle state in the teensy HID sketch, that's pretty trivial software logic too - *except* for not knowing what state it may start out in when someone fires up the application *without* power cycling or re-enumerating the teensy.

Comment: Right -- so would it be a good idea to look into using an edge-detecting loop in the Teensy for this (at least for the actual automation of the double-press events)?

Comment: Exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Great -- thanks for the tips @ChrisStratton and @Passerby!

Comment: Those switches are available in momentary action type. I've used five of them on a foot-switch Powerpoint / presentation controller.

Comment: @Transistor I'm not surprised, but none of my local retailers carry them, and I'm trying to get this together on short notice, so shipping isn't really an option.

Comment: `I'm looking at workarounds at the software level` ... there is no workaround for a latching switch ... there is no "release" signal from the switch ... you have to depress it again to get the "release" signal .... you could try opening the switch and removing the latch mechanism

Comment: @jsotola a software-implementable workaround was proposed (inferred?) which uses rising and falling edge detection, which is most likely going to be sufficient in this case.

Comment: software workaround is not possible ... it would require a "release button" signal ... the switch is able to provide that signal by being pressed a second time ... it does not provide that signal when the button is released

Comment: @jsotola I understand what you're saying, but checking for the falling edge should be effectively equivalent in this application (correct me if I'm wrong, though).

Comment: no, you do not understand. there is no falling edge until you press the button the second time ... i think that if the switch had a paddle type actuator, then you would not be experiencing the same confusion

Answer (score 1):

If you want a push-to-talk switch, replace the button you have with a momentary pushbutton - no microcontroller or logic required.

Comment: As ideal as this would be, I unfortunately won't have access to a momentary pushbutton in this format within a reasonable amount of time. You're completely right that this would solve my problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Treat it like a spst, leaving one side disconnected. The side you use,  wire it like any momentary push button, with a pull up resistor.

Your microcontroller code handles the rest as you describe. When pressed, an interrupt enables the speech control, then waits until the switch is pressed again, to send the mute command.

The physical state, the mechanical action of the switch doesn't affect it's electrical behavior, and the rest you handle in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to reliably implement this kind of logic in the Teensy
>   given that the switch I've got on hand is a push on/push off?

No of course not - when you release your foot the switch stays latched until you press the switch again. Implementing a solution using all the processing power in the world doesn't overcome the physical obstacle that a push_on push_off switch doesn't do what you want.